# Get video stream from multiple cameras in Java using OpenCV

Tags: java, multithreading, opencv, camera, video-streaming

How can I display the video stream from 3 webcameras in Java Swing using OpenCV?

I can do it for 1 camera but I cannot succeed to do it for 2 cameras at least.

Here is my code that tries to display 2 camera streams.  Even if the cameras are started, I don't get any video.

```
public class Test1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    // definitions

    private DaemonThread myThread=null;
    private DaemonThread2 secondThread=null;
    int count=0;
    VideoCapture webSource=null;
    VideoCapture webSource2=null;

    Mat frame=new Mat();
    MatOfByte mem = new MatOfByte();

    Mat frame2=new Mat();
    MatOfByte mem2 = new MatOfByte();





  class DaemonThread implements Runnable
  {


    protected volatile boolean runnable = false;

    @Override
    public  void run()
    {
        synchronized(this)
        {
            while(runnable)
            {
                if(webSource.grab())
                {
                try
                        {
                            webSource.retrieve(frame);
                            //webSource2.retrieve(frame2);


                Highgui.imencode(".bmp", frame, mem);
                Image im = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(mem.toArray()));

                         //     Highgui.imencode(".bmp", frame2, mem2);
               // Image im2 = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(mem2.toArray()));

                BufferedImage buff = (BufferedImage) im;
                Graphics g=jPanel1.getGraphics();

                         //   BufferedImage buff2 = (BufferedImage) im2;
              //  Graphics g2=jPanel2.getGraphics();


                if (g.drawImage(buff, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight() -150 , 0, 0, buff.getWidth(), buff.getHeight(), null))
               // if (g2.drawImage(buff2, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight() -150 , 0, 0, buff2.getWidth(), buff2.getHeight(), null))

                if(runnable == false)
                            {
                    System.out.println("Going to wait()");
                    this.wait();
                }
             }
             catch(Exception ex)
                         {
                System.out.println("Error");
                         }
                }
            }
        }
     }
   }


    class DaemonThread2 implements Runnable
  {


    protected volatile boolean runnable = false;

    @Override
    public  void run()
    {
        synchronized(this)
        {
            while(runnable)
            {
                if(webSource2.grab())
                {
                try
                        {
                            webSource2.retrieve(frame2);
                            //webSource2.retrieve(frame2);


                Highgui.imencode(".bmp", frame2, mem2);
                Image im = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(mem2.toArray()));

                         //     Highgui.imencode(".bmp", frame2, mem2);
               // Image im2 = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(mem2.toArray()));

                BufferedImage buff = (BufferedImage) im;
                Graphics g=jPanel2.getGraphics();

                         //   BufferedImage buff2 = (BufferedImage) im2;
              //  Graphics g2=jPanel2.getGraphics();


                if (g.drawImage(buff, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight() -150 , 0, 0, buff.getWidth(), buff.getHeight(), null))
               // if (g2.drawImage(buff2, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight() -150 , 0, 0, buff2.getWidth(), buff2.getHeight(), null))

                if(runnable == false)
                            {
                    System.out.println("Going to wait()");
                    this.wait();
                }
             }
             catch(Exception ex)
                         {
                System.out.println("Error");
                         }
                }
            }
        }
     }
   }









    /**
     * Creates new form Test
     */
    public Test1() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 190, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 177, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jButton1.setText("Start");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("Pause");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 169, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(74, 74, 74)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 141, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addGap(67, 67, 67))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(19, 19, 19)
                        .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 78, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jButton2))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:


        webSource=new VideoCapture(0);
        webSource2=new VideoCapture(1);


        myThread=new DaemonThread();
        Thread t=new Thread(myThread);
        t.setDaemon(true);
        myThread.runnable=true;


        t.start();

        secondThread=new DaemonThread2();
        Thread t2=new Thread(secondThread);
        t2.setDaemon(true);

        t2.start();

        jButton1.setEnabled(false);
        jButton2.setEnabled(true);
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        myThread.runnable=false;
        jButton2.setEnabled(false);
        jButton1.setEnabled(true);

        webSource.release();

    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Test1().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Try to make this question more specific by showing your attempts at displaying 2 camera streams and explaining why it doesn't work.

Comment: I have no video on my JForm, even if the cameras are both started.